# Guava Rate Limiter Implementation

Tags: java, guava, rate-limiting

I am trying to implement a Rate Limiter Interceptor.
If i just limit the number of call to 1 per second and do not provide a cap on the size, is there a default cap that is set. If yes, how to increase it.

```
public void setRateLimiterForTenantApi(String tenant, String route, double rate) {
    RateLimiter customLimiter = RateLimiter.create(rate);
    limiterMap.put(tenant+route, customLimiter);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying?

Comment: @user7: edited the post, basic implementation.
How to put a cap on the size of the output or increase the cap size.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by cap on the output size? Can you please elaborate?